# Why singleton object is made through class methods?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, singleton

We always make singleton object through Class method.What will happened if i make that method instance(use - instead of +) and call that method through a nil object or simply through an object?

Comment: you could do that, but its a very round about way of doing it, instead of going `[SomeClass getSingleton]`, you would have to make a `SomeClass` object instance, then call a method to get the singleton object.

Comment: So if i made SomeClass object instance,should i need to allocate memory to it or use nil object.If i allocate memory to object ,then after calling the singleton method through that object, that object will point to different memory location and can cause memory leak.

Comment: i think you are maybe misunderstanding what a singleton is (or maybe just the point of one). and like jacks answer below stated, you cant call any methods on a nil object, so that wont be possible. also re-read this sentence carefully "So if i made SomeClass object instance,should i need to allocate memory to it" if you made an instance, surely you have alloced memory to it? im not sure what you are getting at

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually a the `instance` method is not attached to any specific instance of a class.

This means that from a design point of view it doesn't make sense to invoke it on an existing object. It's like requiring that a `+(int) sum:(int)a with:(int)b` should be an instance method when it doesn't need to know anything about an object.

In addition usually a singleton class constructor shouldn't be accessible from clients, if you need to instantiate one to call `-instance` on it this would defeat the purpose.

Last thing, a singleton should be the only possible instance of an object, if you need to have one to instantiate one then you are in a deadlock: you need an instance to create an instance but you are no allowed to have more than an instance.

Regarding calling it on `nil` object, if I remember correctly a pointer returned from a message sent to `nil` will always be `nil` too.